# Section in HTML & CSS

Tags: css

After creating my `Header`, I would like to put a `Section` with a paragraph but the problem is that I don't see my paragraph in my page.

Here is an example:

```
<section>
    <p>test</p>
</section>
```

[image]

Why my Section is hidden? I forgot a step? I can solve my problem with the property: `margin-top` but I think it is not recommended.

Thank you for your help, I am a beginner.

Here is my code below

```css
body{
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
    }

    header{
     font-size: 11px;
     font-weight: 700;
     color: #777;
     line-height: 20px;
    }


    .banner {
      height: 550px; 
      width: 1366px; 
      position: absolute;

    }

    .transparent{
        position: relative;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.5;
        height: 100px;
        width: 1366px;
        padding-top: 8px;
     
    }

    .page-left{
     top: 1px;
     color:white;
     position: absolute;
     display: inline-block;
     left: 430px;
    }

    .page-left-languages{
     top: 1px;
     color:white;
     position: absolute;
     display: inline-block;
     left: 515px;
    }

    .page-right{
     top: 1px;
     color:white;
     position: absolute;
     display: inline-block;
     float: right;
     right: 134px;
    }

    .page-right-login{
     top: 1px;
     color:white;
     position: absolute;
     display: inline-block;
     float: right;
     right: 80px;
    }

    nav{
     position: absolute;
     top: 44px;
     float: right;
     right: 92px;
    }

    nav ul{
     list-style: none;
    }

    nav ul li{
     display: inline-block;
     font-family: "Lato","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-transform: uppercase;
        line-height: 27px;
    }

    nav ul li a{
     padding: 8px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
        color: #FFF;
     text-decoration: center;
     border-radius: 3px
    }

    nav ul li a:hover{
     background-color: #FFF;
     color: black;
    }

    .active{
     background-color: #cd2122;
     color: #FFF;
     padding: 8px 16px;
     border-radius: 3px;
    }

    .background-color-one{
     position: absolute;
     color: #fff;
        font-size: 28px;
        line-height: 1.3;
        border-left: 5px solid #fff;
        background-color: #000;
        left: 20px;
        bottom: 290px;
        padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    }

    .background-color-two{
     position: absolute;
     color: #fff;
        font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 1.3;
        background-color: #000;
        left: 20px;
        bottom: 215px;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    }

    .background-color-three{
     position: absolute;
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 16px;
     line-height: 1.3;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.5;
        left: 20px;
        bottom: 180px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
      <header>
        <img class="banner" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/13/5or2.jpg"/>
         <div class="transparent">    </div> 
            <div class="page-left">Portfolio</div>
            <div class="page-left-languages">Languages</div>
            <div class="page-right">Support</div>
            <div class="page-right-login">Login</div>  
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="active"><href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"> Plan</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Commission</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
             <div class="background-color-one">7.6%-18% daily for 16 days</div>
             <div class="background-color-two">Min deposit $10-Max deposit $50,000</div>
             <div class="background-color-three">We accept Perfectmoney,Payeer and Bitcoin</div>
      </header>

      <section>
        <p>test</p>

      </section>
     


     </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler to give your body a background-image. Use [flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) for your navigation. It makes things simple.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #000 url('https://zupimages.net/up/20/13/5or2.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
  background-size: cover;
}

header {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #777;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0 0 2rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#nav-secondary {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Lato", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #cd2122;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

main {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.background-color-one {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  border-left: 5px solid #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.background-color-two {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.background-color-three {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav id="nav-secondary">
      <ul class="nav-secondary-left-list">
        <li><a class="active" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Languages</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav-secondary-right-list">
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <nav id="nav-primary">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Plan</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Commission</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>

    <section>
      <div class="background-color-one">7.6%-18% daily for 16 days</div>
      <div class="background-color-two">Min deposit $10-Max deposit $50,000</div>
      <div class="background-color-three">We accept Perfectmoney,Payeer and Bitcoin</div>
    </section>

    <section>
      <p>test</p>
    </section>

  </main>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel, I understood.

Comment: This is by no means a ready design. Just enough to get things started. Lot of work in front of you. Have fun exploring.

Answer (score 1):

Your image is positioned absolutely and "in front of" your section. There are more elegant ways to use an image as a background, like using a CSS-background-image on your body. 
But using your code, it would be a quick fix to give your image a negative z-index, so that it steps behind your section:

```css
body{
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
    }

    header{
     font-size: 11px;
     font-weight: 700;
     color: #777;
     line-height: 20px;
    }


    .banner {
      height: 550px; 
      width: 1366px; 
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1; /* added */
    }

    .transparent{
        position: relative;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.5;
        height: 100px;
        width: 1366px;
        padding-top: 8px;
     
    }

    .page-left{
     top: 1px;
     color:white;
     position: absolute;
     display: inline-block;
     left: 430px;
    }

    .page-left-languages{
     top: 1px;
     color:white;
     position: absolute;
     display: inline-block;
     left: 515px;
    }

    .page-right{
     top: 1px;
     color:white;
     position: absolute;
     display: inline-block;
     float: right;
     right: 134px;
    }

    .page-right-login{
     top: 1px;
     color:white;
     position: absolute;
     display: inline-block;
     float: right;
     right: 80px;
    }

    nav{
     position: absolute;
     top: 44px;
     float: right;
     right: 92px;
    }

    nav ul{
     list-style: none;
    }

    nav ul li{
     display: inline-block;
     font-family: "Lato","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-transform: uppercase;
        line-height: 27px;
    }

    nav ul li a{
     padding: 8px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
        color: #FFF;
     text-decoration: center;
     border-radius: 3px
    }

    nav ul li a:hover{
     background-color: #FFF;
     color: black;
    }

    .active{
     background-color: #cd2122;
     color: #FFF;
     padding: 8px 16px;
     border-radius: 3px;
    }

    .background-color-one{
     position: absolute;
     color: #fff;
        font-size: 28px;
        line-height: 1.3;
        border-left: 5px solid #fff;
        background-color: #000;
        left: 20px;
        bottom: 290px;
        padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    }

    .background-color-two{
     position: absolute;
     color: #fff;
        font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 1.3;
        background-color: #000;
        left: 20px;
        bottom: 215px;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    }

    .background-color-three{
     position: absolute;
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 16px;
     line-height: 1.3;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.5;
        left: 20px;
        bottom: 180px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
      <header>
        <img class="banner" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/13/5or2.jpg"/>
         <div class="transparent">    </div> 
            <div class="page-left">Portfolio</div>
            <div class="page-left-languages">Languages</div>
            <div class="page-right">Support</div>
            <div class="page-right-login">Login</div>  
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="active"><href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"> Plan</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Commission</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
             <div class="background-color-one">7.6%-18% daily for 16 days</div>
             <div class="background-color-two">Min deposit $10-Max deposit $50,000</div>
             <div class="background-color-three">We accept Perfectmoney,Payeer and Bitcoin</div>
      </header>

      <section>
        <p>test</p>

      </section>
     


     </body>
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, but why the paragraph is always at the top and not at the bottom?

Comment: You might want to read about absolute positioning. It takes elements out of the natural flow of the page. Other elements are still in the flow. The section follows the header. The header is only 108px high. So your Paragraph is right underneath the header. Your black div's with text are positioned absolutely, so they are taken out of the text flow. You position them absolutely, in context to the left and botttom of a positioned parent element. Have a look on a big screen and see what happens with those div's:
[Screenshot on Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/RAFyaN1.jpg)

Comment: Hey Joel. Search for tutorials explaining the differences between **static (default value), relative, absolute, fixed** and you will be up to the task in no time. It's confusing in the beginning, but it's time well spent. I like this tut: https://marksheet.io/css-position.html